# createSchemaValidation is not defined

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

PS D:\React Prep\E-com> npm start

> ecom@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Failed to compile.

createSchemaValidation is not defined

error showing while npm start..

Comment: I advise you give the code you wrote that is relevant to this error, as well as what you have tried and anything else that may be relevant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.